# How to make the autocompletetextfield in Wicket work after the session timed out

Tags: java, session, autocomplete, wicket

I've been playing with the Wicket autocompletetextfield. It has one problem though - when the session times out it stops working if the page itself isn't refreshed. This would be quite confusing for a customer I think, and I guess that it's not meant to work that way. Therefore, how can I make the Wicket autocompletetextfield work even though the session has timed out (and without refreshing the page)

To try it yourself:

1. Go to http://www.wicket-library.com/wicket-examples-6.0.x/ajax/autocomplete
2. Write something in the textfield, eg. bel
3. Wait for 5 minutes (I think that's is the default session timeout they use in the examples) and try again, without refreshing
   the page.    Now you'll only get a blank textfield.

Comment: AutoCompleteTextField is stateful, thus it needs its page alive. You could try using a pure-javascript autocomplete component ([jQueryUI has one](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)), and feed it with JSON generated by a Resource from Wicket (this will be stateless).

Comment: Thanks, this is the answer I was looking for. For what I know I can't set pages with AJAX-components on them as stateless (in Wicket 1.6x at least), so I will have to think about an alternative solution. Another solution I've seen is the one where you ping an servlet every X mins to keep the session alive.

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't.

The only workaround I know is to set the Ajax error handling strategy to REDIRECT_TO_ERROR_PAGE, evaluate the Referer-Field in the HTTP header in the Error Page and provide a link (or auto redirect) to the page where the timeout occurred.

YourWicketApplication.java

```
@Override
public void init() {
    super.init();
    // ...
    getExceptionSettings().setAjaxErrorHandlingStrategy(IExceptionSettings.AjaxErrorStrategy.REDIRECT_TO_ERROR_PAGE);

}
```

YourErrorPage.java:

```
public YourErrorPage(...) {
    // ...
    WebRequest request = (WebRequest) getRequest();
    String referer = request.getHeader("Referer"));
    // ... provide a link/auto redirect to this address
}
```